# How to make mysql query faster

Tags: mysql, performance

## SOLVED BY MR @RolandStarke

change DATE( t4.`date`) to t4.`date` and it will use the index

> Query took 0.5519 seconds.

---

i'm trying to make this query more faster i tried this

## First query# without joins

```
SELECT `productTitle`,`orderCnt`,`promPCPriceStr`,`productImgUrl`,`oriPriceStr`,`detailUrl`,
(
select count(id) from orders t4 WHERE
 t4.productId = t1.productId 
and DATE( t4.`date`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
) as ordertoday 

FROM `products` t1 
WHERE `orderCnt` > 0 
AND `orderCnt` < 2000 
AND `promPCPriceStr` > 0 
AND `promPCPriceStr` < 2000 
HAVING ordertoday > 5 AND ordertoday < 2000 
order by ordertoday desc limit 150
```

The result is

> Query took 4.0222 seconds.

Explain result

[image: 1]

## Second query# with join

```
SELECT  `productTitle`,`orderCnt`,`promPCPriceStr`,`productImgUrl`,`oriPriceStr`,`detailUrl` FROM `products` p 
INNER JOIN
(
select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE DATE( t4.`date`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)  
GROUP by productId
) o

ON p.productID = o.productId

AND `orderCnt` > 0 AND `orderCnt` < 2000 AND `promPCPriceStr` > 0 AND `promPCPriceStr` < 2000 
and filterd_orders > 5 
AND filterd_orders < 2000 
order by filterd_orders desc limit 30
```

> Query took 4.8217 seconds.

Explain result

[image: 1]

## Subquery Result

```
select count(id) AS filterd_orders,productId from orders t4 WHERE DATE( t4.`date`) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) GROUP by productId
```

> Query took 0.0044 seconds.

Explain result

[image: 1]

## Tables Structure

Products table

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `detailUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `belongToDSStore` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `promPCPriceStr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `oriPriceStr` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 `orderCnt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `productTitle` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `productImgUrl` text CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL,
 `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `cat` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `productId` (`productId`),
 KEY `orderCnt` (`orderCnt`),
 KEY `cat` (`cat`),
 KEY `promPCPriceStr` (`promPCPriceStr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37773 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Orders table

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
 `oid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `countryCode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `productId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`oid`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `date` (`date`),
 KEY `productId` (`productId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9790205 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

## Also

> innodb_buffer_pool_size =
>   {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}

## Server hardware

- AWS RDS db.t2.medium
- 4 GB RAM
- 2 CPU Cores 2.5Hz

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for performance improvements to working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: but it has problems not only performance as example the queries are not using the indexes ,and i don't know how to make the query use them this a problem

Comment: @RolandStarke Will you are a star my man,i spent a week on this and that signal tweaks made the query to go to Query took 0.8783 seconds.,that solve my problem i learned the hard way , may the creator blessing be on you , if i got rich one day i will remember you have a nice day

Comment: Oh and I thought my comment was useless and I deleted it. So here again for others: `DATE( t4.date) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)` can't use the index on `date` use `t4.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)` instead.

Comment: @RolandStarke you can post it as answer if you like.